# Getting Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error on iOS app with ar6unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, artoolkit, mach

I have the exact same issue as this; [Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error on ar6unity iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45246110/apple-mach-o-linker-id-error-on-ar6unity-ios)

Unfortunately the link to the accepted answer in that post is broken.

I've been trying all sorts of other Mach-O linker error solutions;

- Clean & Rebuild
- Deleted derived data
- Installed Boost libraries and linked them
- Enabled / Disabled Bitcode
- Enabled / Disabled Dead code stripping
- Re-adding frameworks

Nothing works.

Anybody have any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: This is a good comment to have on the question, but itself doesn't provide and answer and should not be posted as one :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error on ar6unity iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45246110/apple-mach-o-linker-id-error-on-ar6unity-ios)

Comment: I referred to the "duplicate" and said I have the exact same problem, but since the accepted answer in that question no longer leads to a solution it is in fact not answered. And since I don't have a high enough reputation I'm not able to comment on the accepted answer in the other post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to rebuild the boost libraries for IOS, and make sure to include the 'serialization' library when building.

I used https://github.com/danoli3/ofxiOSBoost and customized the build scripts to include support for armv7s and added the serialization library.

Then I had to include the built files in my XCode project and add the library to Library Search Path and the headers to Header Search Paths.